# Enable WIFI Channel 14 iw reg get country 00 DFS-UNSET

Tags: linux, wifi, intel, yocto, iw

Hardware: Intel **Galileo** Gen 2

System: **Yocto** linux (iot-devkit-image)

User: root

```
# iw reg set JP
# iw reg get

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
        (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
        (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
        (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
        (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
        (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
        (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

# iw list

Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
```

Notes :

- "iw" not installed by default on Yocto, so i compiled it from source code.
- All i want enable wifi channel 14.
- "iw" and same wifi adapter work good on Ubunte 17 (without no-IR flag).

**How to** fix "iw", or any other way to **enable channel 14**, or **remove no-IR flag**?

Comment: Thank you for every one :) [Answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413916/267615)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that `iw reg get` still indicates your country code is 00 suggests that your attempt to set the country code failed.

If `iw` was not installed by default, you may also be missing `/sbin/crda`. There should also be an udev rule like

```
KERNEL=="regulatory*", ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="platform", RUN+="/sbin/crda"
```

for loading the country-specific regulatory information from `[/usr]/lib/crda/regulatory.bin` when requested by the kernel (including but not limited to when `iw reg set` command is used).

After a successful `iw reg set JP`, the `iw reg get` command should say something like:

```
global
country JP: DFS-JP
    (2402.000 - 2482.000 @ 40.000), (20.00), (N/A)
    (2474.000 - 2494.000 @ 20.000), (20.00), (N/A), NO-OFDM
    (4910.000 - 4990.000 @ 40.000), (23.00), (N/A)
    (5030.000 - 5090.000 @ 40.000), (23.00), (N/A)
    (5170.000 - 5250.000 @ 80.000), (20.00), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5250.000 - 5330.000 @ 80.000), (20.00), (N/A), DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5490.000 - 5710.000 @ 160.000), (23.00), (N/A), DFS
    (59000.000 - 66000.000 @ 2160.000), (10.00), (N/A)
```

The Linux wireless regulatory system [is described here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/regulatory), with links to source code of various components.

Comment: Thank you, I'am new Linux user, So, How to install "crda" ?

Comment: # KERNEL=="regulatory*", ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="platform", RUN+="/sbin/crda"

# iw reg set JP

# iw reg get

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
...

# cd /sbin/crda
-sh: cd: /sbin/crda: No such file or directory

Comment: Since you already had to compile `iw` from source and I can't seem to easily find a list of tools included in Yocto, [here is a link to crda source and documentation](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/regulatory/crda).

Comment: ... and [here is a link to where you can find the regulatory.bin file](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/regulatory/wireless-regdb), just in case you'll need it. Actually, here's the overall description of the regulatory infrastructure: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/regulatory

Comment: crda is provided by meta-openembedded. You can get on `meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-connectivity/crda`. Implement meta-openembedded on your codebase, and write on `./build/conf/local.conf` this code `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " crda " `

Comment: For `iw`, you can found it on `poky/meta/recipes-connectivity/iw` and install it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your router supports  802.11d, it broadcasts your country domain. iwlwifi drivers will use the first 802.11d beacon they see.

Enabling 802.11d on my router fixed this issue for me.