# crda make error

Tags: linux, wifi, intel, yocto, iw

Hardware: Intel **Galileo** Gen 2

System: **Yocto** linux (iot-devkit-image)

User: root

At "**Step 7**" of this [Post](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/ultimate-guide-upping-tx-power-kali-linux-2-0-0168325/)

```
root@dhcppc6:~/crda-3.18# make
  GEN  keys-gcrypt.c
  Trusted pubkeys: pubkeys/root.key.pub.pem pubkeys/root.x509.pem pubkeys/sforshee.x509.pem pubkeys/sforshee.key.pub.pem pubkeys/benh@debian.org.key.pub.pem pubkeys/linville.key.pub.pem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./utils/key2pub.py", line 149, in <module>
    key = RSA.load_key(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/M2Crypto/RSA.py", line 376, in load_key
    return load_key_bio(bio, callback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/M2Crypto/RSA.py", line 395, in load_key_bio
    rsa_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/M2Crypto/RSA.py", line 330, in rsa_error
    raise RSAError(m2.err_reason_error_string(m2.err_get_error()))
M2Crypto.RSA.RSAError: no start line
Makefile:113: recipe for target 'keys-gcrypt.c' failed
make: *** [keys-gcrypt.c] Error 1
```

when run make again

```
root@dhcppc6:~/crda-3.18# make
  CC   libreg.so
reglib.c: In function 'reglib_verify_db_signature':
reglib.c:168:26: error: 'keys' undeclared (first use in this function)
  for (i = 0; (i < sizeof(keys)/sizeof(keys[0])) && (!ok); i++) {
                          ^
reglib.c:168:26: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'libreg.so' failed
make: *** [libreg.so] Error 1
```

How to fix "**crda make**" ?

Comment: see [Build requirements](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/regulatory/crda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for every one :)

Install [Build requirements](http://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/regulatory/crda).

Do like this [post](http://networkgeekstuff.com/networking/how-to-create-custom-linux-wi-fi-regulatory-database-to-unlock-30db1000mw/).

Or like this [Post](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/ultimate-guide-upping-tx-power-kali-linux-2-0-0168325/).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error by deleting files contains x509 in name from pubkeys folder.

Comment: That would result in a `crda` binary that will not accept data from any source, because it will have no compiled-in trusted public keys at all. It may "work" in the sense that the binary can be executed, but with that binary you'll be unable to unlock any frequencies outside the globally-available minimum default set that the kernel uses if there is no CRDA information.